# Canadian stocks' financials different than what is stated on yahoo finance website

Tags: python, yfinance

When trying to retrieve financial statement information for Canadian stocks using the yfinance module in python, the information being retrieved is different than what is actually stated on the yahoo finance website. For example, when retrieving the latest quarter's income statement for RBC (ticker RY.TO on yahoo finance), the 2020-10-31 quarterly revenue figure is $10,665,000,000. However, on the yahoo finance website, the 2020-10-31 quarterly revenue figure is $11,072,000. When retrieving the same information for Tesla (ticker TSLA on yahoo finance), the quarterly income statement information matches. This problem seems to only occur for Canadian stocks. Could not figure out why there is a difference.

Below is the code I used to retrieve the latest quarter's income statement information. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated!

```
import yfinance as yf

companyFinancials = yf.Ticker('RY.TO').quarterly_financials

for x, row in enumerate(companyFinancials.values):

    if companyFinancials.index[x] == "Total Revenue":
        quarterlyRevenue = row[0]
```

Comment: I used the package [yahoo_fin](http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/) to get it, but it was the same as yfinance. In cases like this, I think it's best to actually check the target company's annual report.

Comment: You don't need to do any looping to get it. `quarterlyRevenue = companyFinancials.loc['Total Revenue'][0]`